# How to make a wpf datagrid fill all available space and resize with window?

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

How to make a wpf datagrid fill all available space and resize with window?
Mind that the datagrid is inside a grid.

Comment: Show your code. Your parent grid has to be set up properly as well depending on the `code`.

Comment: As @dirt requested please show the code. Generally I don't use `Grid` for this particular reason. Whenever I need my controls to be dynamically re-sized I use `DockPanel` and `StackPanel` to arrange my controls. It provides a lot of flexibility since `DockPanel` fills the available space with the last defined logical child

Answer (score 32):

You should be able to do it for a datagrid (or for any WPF control) by setting `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` to `Stretch`

If it's inside a Grid, you should be able to set something like this

```
<Grid> <!-- parent grid or whatever -->
   <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ... >
   </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You might also want to set `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` on your `Window` control.

Comment: `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` declarations are useless since [`Stretch` is the default value.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.horizontalalignment?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#definition)

Answer (score 11):

1. Never set height or width to it or its parent control
2. No need to worry on the horizontal and vertical alignment since by default Horizontal and vertical alignment are stretch.
   if above are proper things should work :)

Answer (score 4):

Set the width for the last column of the DataGrid to *.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Notes"
                    Binding="{Binding Notes}"
                    Width="*"/>
```

Note : This actually works on only the last column of the DataGrid

Comment: The * star is an invalid input for the Width

Comment: @MohamedKamelBouzekria, they why does it do exactly what I want it to do?

Comment: @MohamedKamelBouzekria, thanks for the edit, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 3):

Remove all height and width property of its parent control. remove horizontal and vertical property. Define row height as * of its parent grid.

```
<Grid> 
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition Height="*"/>
<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" >
   </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It is not a Grid, it is DataGrid

Comment: The DataGrid is located in the Grid.

Answer (score -1):

Insert DataGrid directly to the Grid without wrapping with a panel.

```
    <Grid>
       <DataGrid>
       </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: This won't work as the DataGrid will take as much space as it needs and not fill all the space available

Comment: Ironically, this is the correct answer.